# Can training label confidence be used to improve prediction accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, scikit-learn, svm

I have training data that is labelled with binary values. I also have collected the confidence of each of these labels i.e. 0.8 confidence would mean that 80% of the human labellers agree on that label.

Is it possible to use this confidence data to improve the accuracy of my classifier?

Would the following work?

- 1a) If the label is 0 and the confidence data for that label is 0.8
  then give the training data a new label of 0.2
- 1b) If the label is 1 and the confidence data for that label is 0.8
  then give the training data a new label of 0.8
- 2) Calculate the new label using this method for every entry in the
  training set
- 3) Treat the problem as a regression problem (where the labels range
  between 0 and 1)
- 4) Classify unlabelled data based on whether the new labels are above
  or below a specific value. i.e Give all predicted labels class 0 if below X and class 1 if above X.

I am currently using a SVM with an RBF kernel for my model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Classifier for uncertain class labels](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74042/classifier-for-uncertain-class-labels)

Comment: So for now you are using the binary label ? I don't know why it wouldn't work. Test it. Split your data into a training test and a validation test and see if you increase your prediction.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to use this confidence data.  However, I wouldn't recommend the approach you mention.  Instead, let me suggest a different approach.  Actually, I'll suggest two.  The first one is conceptually clean; the second is probably easier to implement; and they'll probably be approximately equivalent in practice.

### Adjust the loss function

You can adjust the loss function to reflect the confidence scores you have on the training data.

In particular, if you are using the [cross-entropy loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_error_function_and_logistic_regression), there's a particularly clean way to do this.  Let me explain some background on the cross-entropy loss, then explain how.  We think of the label on the training instance as a probability distribution on labels.  In binary classification, such a distribution can be represented as a vector $(p_0,p_1)$ where $p_0$ represents the probability that the label is 0 and $p_1$ the probability that the label is 1.  Normally, we are given "hard labels": if we know that the correct label on instance $x$ is 0, then that corresponds to the probability distribution $(1,0)$; if the correct label is 1, that's the distribution $(0,1)$.  The cross-entropy loss then compares the prediction from the classifier to this distribution.

The nice thing about the cross-entropy loss is that it generates readily to comparing any two distributions.  Thus, if you have a confidence $0.8$ that the correct label for instance $x$ is 0, then that corresponds to a probability distribution $(0.8,0.2)$.  Now, you can compute the cross-entropy of the classifier's prediction with respect to the distribution $(0.8,0.2)$, and that is the contribution to the loss from training instance $x$.  Sum this over all instances in the training set, and you get an adjusted loss function.

Now you can train a classifier by minimizing this adjusted loss function, and that will directly incorporate all of the information in your confidence scores.

### Use weights

Alternatively, you can use weights to reflect the confidence information.

Some classifiers allow you to specify a *weight* for each instance in the training set.  The idea is that a misprediction for a particular instance is penalized proportionality to its weight, so instances with a high weight are more important to get right and instances with a low weight are less important.  Or, equivalently, the training procedure tries harder to avoid errors on instances with a high weight.

You can use weights to reflect confidence information.  Suppose you have an instanced $x$ in the training set that you think should have label 0, with confidence $0.8$.  You would add one copy of $(x,0)$ to the training set with weight $0.8$ (i.e., instance is $x$ and label is 0), and add one copy of $(x,1)$ to the training set with weight $0.2$ (i.e., instance is $x$ and label is 1).  Build up the training set in this way.  This doubles the size of your training set.  Now train a classifier, using these weights.

For classifiers that support weights, this should be easy to implement.

One can also show that it is effective and reasonable.  For instance, when using the cross-entropy loss to train a classifier, this approach using weights is equivalent to adjusting the loss function as highlighted above.  So, in that particular context, the two approaches are actually equivalent.